# Error with loading objects from a Response(RestKit)

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit

I created a mapping for the rest Response and named it Data.After making the rest call through RKObjectManager,it is not loading the objects.Instead it is executing the didFailWithError method of RKObjetLoader.My implementation class inherits from RKObjectLoaderDelegate.

```
@implementation RKObjectLoaderExamples

    -(void)loadData{
        RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]];
        RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service"];  
        [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/process-definitions?start=0&size=10&sort=id&order=asc&username=kermit&password=kermit" objectMapping:mapping delegate:self]  ;
        NSLog(@"Loaded Data");
    }

    // RKObjectLoaderDelegate methods  

    - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {  
        NSLog(@"objectLoaded");
        Data* data = [objects objectAtIndex:0];  
        NSLog(@"Loaded Key: %@, Name: %@", data.key, data.name);  
    }  


    - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {  
        NSLog(@"Encountered an error: %@", error);  
    }
@end
```

The error messages i am getting are as follows

```
2011-11-16 14:36:38.971 Views[16753:fb03] W restkit.network:RKResponse.m:182 Received an authentication challenge without any credentials to satisfy the request.
2011-11-16 14:36:38.974 Views[16753:fb03] W restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:242 Unable to find parser for MIME Type 'text/html'
2011-11-16 14:36:38.975 Views[16753:fb03] W restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:259 Encountered unexpected response with status code: 401 (MIME Type: text/html)
2011-11-16 14:36:38.976 Views[16753:fb03] Encountered an error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain error 4.)"
```

Please help!

After correction i changed the function as

```
-(void)loadData{

    [RKClient setSharedClient:[[RKClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service"]];
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]];
    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service"];  
     [manager setClient:[RKClient sharedClient]];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] setUsername:@"kermit"];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] setPassword:@"kermit"];
    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/process-definitions?start=0&size=10&sort=id&order=asc" objectMapping:mapping delegate:self]  ;
    NSLog(@"Loaded Data");

}
```

Is it correct?Because now object seems to be loaded but i am getting an index 0 beyond bounds for an empty array.Am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your API returns HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized. Does your backend require a HTTP authentication? If so, supply the correct credentials to the `RKClient`:

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] setUsername:myUsername];
[[RKClient sharedClient] setPassword:myPassword];
```

**edit:**

I believe you have some fundamental problems in setting up the RestKit. Consider the following example.

```
//in your appdelegate
RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service"]; 
[[RKClient sharedClient] setUsername:@"kermit"];
[RKClient sharedClient] setPassword:@"kermit"];

// don't forget to create your mapping here
RKObjectMapping *dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]];
[dataMapping mapKeyPath:@"myKeyPath" toAttribute:@"myAttr"];
[[manager mappingProvider] addObjectMapping: dataMapping];
```

then, you can do just this.

```
 -(void)loadData{
    // fetch your mapping
    [RKObjectMapping *mapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Data class]]; 
    //request data
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/process-definitions?start=0&size=10&sort=id&order=asc" objectMapping:mapping delegate:self];
}
```

Firstly, you need to do the setup (`RKClient`, mappings and `RKObjectManager`) - you do it just *once*. They are singletons, so the settings are kept. I found that best place to do this is the AppDelegate - feel free to experiment, but be sure to make the setup before you do any requests.

When you are about to do any requests just use your `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` singleton to load the actual objects.

Also, i recommend you reading some documentation, eg. the [Object Mapping guide](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md%20%22Object%20Mapping%22%20guide)

Comment: Yes it requires authentication.So i tried to attach it as part of the query string.But if i am making the rest 'get' with RKObjectManager,does it not mean that i should get away with RKClient?How should i use RKClient with RKObjectManager?

Comment: How you handle authentication depends on your backend. If your backend require auth data in the query string - you do the right thing. However, if your backend require HTTP Basic access authentication you should use RKClient to supply the credentials to received auth. challenge. You just set up the credentials once and they will be used by RestKit when needed.

Comment: Okay, i overlooked the log statement. You definitely need to setup credentials for RKClient. As the RKClient is a singleton, it doens't really matter where you place the code, just make sure it's called before you load objects with manager

Comment: Do you need multiple RKObjectManagers? (ie. you access more baseUrls) if not it's a bit overcomplicated. Do you still have the same error?

Comment: I used only one RKObjectManager right?U mean i should configure the client with baseURL again?I edited the question again.Did u see the error i mentioned?

Comment: see my updated answer. You are defining new, empty mapping with this code: `RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]];` so the restkit does not have any idea how to map your API response to Data class. So, your initial problem is resolved (authentication) - but you still have to define the mapping.

Comment: Can you please tell me if the lines of code in your loadData is correct.I am not able to correct the bug but that is causing the build to fail ??

Comment: that should not cause the build to fail, but as i already said i don't think you are defining the mapping in a correct way - see my previous comments and answer.